# Upload & include specific JavaScript files for posts?

Tags: custom-field

I need to include specific Javascript files on specific posts. This will be done in pretty much every post and each file is unlikely to be included in more than one post. I know I could just upload the files via FTP and put a `<script>` tag at the bottom of the post, but I would like to do it all from the dashboard.

So I want to create a custom field in post-new.php where I can upload javascript files to the database, then in single.php I add a line of code that includes the files at the bottom of the page.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upload the file as [media/attachment](http://codex.wordpress.org/Media_Library_Screen), add post meta data and add it as dependency to the footer via [the Dependency API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

Comment: Quick question, is there a reason why I should use the Dependency API instead of a simple `<script>` tag?

Comment: Because you can handle stuff easier, plugins that concatenate and compress scripts can take it into account, you get it at the right position in the DOM, etc.